# Prevent automatic restart of jobservice on rescheduling

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler

I use a JobScheduler to start a JobService (JobSchedulerRefreshService) to refresh some external information. The JobScheduler is set to run periodically. See this code:

```
ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(this, JobSchedulerRefreshService.class);
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(REFRESH_JOB_ID, serviceName)
        .setPeriodic(refreshInterval)
        .setPersisted(true)     // task remains active after reboot
        .setRequiredNetworkType(networkType)
        .setBackoffCriteria(initialBackoffMillis, backoffPolicy)
        .build();
int result = scheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
if (result == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Job (re-)scheduled successfully.");
}
```

The user can set in the preferences what the refresh period should be. As soon as the preference has changed, the JobScheduler is rescheduled with the new `refreshInterval`. However, as soon as the job is rescheduled with `scheduler.schedule(jobInfo)` it also starts the Jobservice `JobSchedulerRefreshService` even if the time period has not been passed yet.

How can I prevent the automatic start of the JobService on each rescheduling of a job?

Comment: What Android version are you using?